# UDP Multicast not receiving data

Tags: c#, .net-core, udp, multicast

I'm trying to write a simple client to receive multicast data. I've tried many different iterations and none of them work. The environment that I am using is .netcore 2.2.2 and in a linux environment. I can see that the data is being sent to the proper interface via tcpdump but my client always gets stuck at the receive. I also have a program that was written in Java by a previous developer which properly receives data from interfaces below so I can confirm that the route does indeed work.

Attempt #1

```
mcastSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                         SocketType.Dgram,
                         ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress localIPAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.51.254.2");
EndPoint localEP = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(localIPAddr, mcastPort);

mcastSocket.Bind(localEP);

mcastOption = new MulticastOption(mcastAddress, localIPAddr);

mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                  SocketOptionName.AddMembership,
                  mcastOption);

EndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(mcastAddress, mcastPort);
// I have tried using (localIPAddr, mcastPort), (IPAddress.Any, 0),
// (localIPAddr, 0), (IPAddress.Any, mcastPort)

byte[] arr = new byte[4096];
Console.WriteLine("Socket setup");
var receivedBytes = mcastSocket.ReceiveFrom(arr, ref remoteEp );
Console.WriteLine("Got data");
```

Attempt#2

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.51.254.2"), 14382);

client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;

client.Client.Bind(localEp);            
client.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("224.0.31.130"), IPAddress.Parse("10.51.254.2"));

Console.WriteLine("Listening this will never quit so you will need to ctrl-c it");
IPEndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.0.31.130"), 14382);
EndPoint remoteEndPoint = (EndPoint) new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
while (true)
{
    Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);                
    Console.WriteLine("got data");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FIXED using the following code

```
try
{
    mcastSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    IPAddress localIPAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.51.254.2");                
    IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, mcastPort);          
    mcastSocket.Bind(localEP);

    MulticastOption option = new MulticastOption(mcastAddress, localIPAddr);              
    mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, option);

    EndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddr, mcastPort);

    byte[] arr = new byte[4096];

    while (true)
    {
        var receivedBytes = mcastSocket.ReceiveFrom(arr, ref remoteEp);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Got data {receivedBytes}");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: See msdn example.  I would use for local IP address the commented out code : IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Any;  Here is the link to the msdn page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.multicastoption?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The code in #1 is taken from the example that you linked

Comment: Try using localIP = IPAddress.Any with "224.0.31.130" in example 1.

Comment: That did it. OMG its such a relief. I will update my code example to reflect working code. THANKS

Comment: @jdweng any idea why IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddr, mcastPort) doesn't work and changing it to IPAddress.Any fixes the issue?

Comment: IP.Any gets all message directly from Ethernet Card for all subnets.  If you have multiple subnets defined on the ethernet card picking one IP Address may not get the data because multicast does not get forwarded through routers.   The multicast could be in one subnet but not all subnets.

Comment: @jdweng awesome. Again thanks for the help. Can you close this ? I don't have enough rep to do so

Comment: Thank you !!! I had the same problem. I could never get it to work with UdpClient. In my case the Linux app is listening on a VLAN interface.

Comment: Hi, Can you post your full code? Im having the same issue, My code works on windows but i don`t get the messages at linux